# catching old url regex

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess

i have variation url to **410** with pattern like this

```
https://www.example.org/falsefalsefalsefalsewp-content/uploads/2019/01/smartphone-385x300.jpg
https://www.example.org/falsefalsefalsefalsewp-content/uploads/2017/12/ime-740x555.jpg
https://www.example.org/falsefalsefalse/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/ime-740x555.jpg
https://www.example.org/falsefalsewp-content/litespeed/avatar/0de3fce48f91d34af7e.jpg
https://www.example.org/falsefalsefalsefal/wp-content/litespeed/avatar/0de3fce48f.jpg
```

im not sure if we can find pattern to match in above url

And another number variation to 301 redirect are

```
https://www.example.org/feeds/5872824853738837815/comments/default
https://www.example.org/feeds/2527275275275257177/comments/default
```

to redirected **301** at `https://www.example.org/feed`

where `5872824853738837815` are random generated string of number

can we used regex for this? if someone can help me I really appreciate

current .htaccess

````
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>```
````

Comment: welcome to SO, please do share your tried htaccess Rules in your question, thank you.

Comment: ```<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>```